# haskell segmentation fault with factorial

Tags: haskell, segmentation-fault

```
GHCi, version 7.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> let fac 0 = 1
Prelude> let fac n = product [1..n]
Prelude> fac 100000
Segmentation fault: 11
```

does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

`fac 10000` works

running on OS X 10.8.2

hmm, so loading from file:

```
fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac 0 = 1
fac n = product [1..n]
```

runs.

also interesting is that using

`fac :: Int -> Int`

returns `0` for `fac 100000`. I would have expected (Just as JohnL) an error.

[this site](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SegmentationFault) mentions:

- More specifically, SegmentationFault is a way a type-unsafe language spells DoesNotUnderstand. In a typesafe statically-typed language like Haskell, you shouldn't see segfaults.

is it something to do with the IO monad?

Comment: If you are going to downvote, please at least explain why.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to diagnose the problem. This is firmly in the category of "should never happen" so something very strange is going on with your system.

Comment: `fac 100000 :: Integer` gives a 456574 digit number on os x here. `fax 100000::Int` is `0 :: Int`, since, to put it a little crudely, its a multiple of 2^32 (or 2^64).

Comment: It's quite possible for examples like this to cause a stack overflow, but there's no way in hell it should segfault...

Comment: It could be a bug on OSX, it could be your install specifically. That should never segfault, and it works here (of course printing that number takes a while). `fac 100000` isn't even enough to cause a stack overflow due to laziness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick test, it appears to be caused by the fact that `product` isn't strict, and the chain of thunks is causing the fault.

In the prelude, `product` is defined as:

```
product = foldl (*) 1
```

If in ghci, you instead define it as:

```
> :m + Data.List
> let product = foldl' (*) 1
> let fac n = product [1..n]
```

Then it should work. I suspect when you specify the type signature, maybe some optimization is kicking in that isn't present otherwise... but haven't dug into it.

Btw, you don't need the `let fac 0 = 1` line.

Answer (score 1):

By giving it a type signature

`fac :: Integer -> Integer`

it will work. I do not fully understand why though.

Comment: Does it work if you give the type signature `fac :: Int -> Int`?  I suspect that will segfault also.

Comment: @JohnL using `fac :: Int -> Int` actually returns `0` for `fac 100000`